# Can we calculate function points for each activity of use case or not?

Tags: use-case, ms-project, estimation, function-points

I am trying to estimate a banking system. So if I consider use case diagram that is in the  design phase.

Do I have to calculate the function points for each use-case activity or calculate function points for whole system as total inputs total outputs ? If I consider as a whole then how can I assign cost and resources for each separate activity in Project Estimation tool like MS Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it any way you want, but software estimation is a field unto itself and there are some best practices it can be very helpful to follow. I found a good starting source is the book "Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art" by Steve McConnell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ballpark rules of thumb such as 30 FP or CFP per use case. Check out Capers Jones "Estimating Software" for more tips such as this.

Alternatively we have automated software size estimation by analysing the text of requirements.  Search on ScopeMaster.
[image: The results of automated size estimation]